# no such file to load -- rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rmagick

I have following -

Gem Version - 1.3.2

Ruby Version - ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]

Rails Version - Rails 2.3.5

========================

rmagick (2.13.1, 2.10.0)

```
Authors: Tim Hunter, Omer Bar-or, Benjamin Thomas
Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rmagick
Homepage: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rmagick
Installed at (2.13.1): /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
             (2.10.0): /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Ruby binding to ImageMagick
```

I have recently update ImageMagick to ImageMagick 6.6.3-10

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.2
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - /home/mbm/.gem/ruby/1.8
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - http://gems.rubyforge.org/

I really wonder why this error is coming. 
Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.3 but ImageMagick 6.4.5 is in use
```

Solution is error message which I couldn't see at very time.
1. Reactivate ImageMagick 6.6.3 (remove 6.4.5)
2. Keep 6.4.5 and install rmagick again.

Thanks guys for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use lowercase ('rmagick'). The correct form is:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'RMagick'
=> true
```

Comment: RuntimeError: This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.3 but ImageMagick 6.4.5 is in use.

 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so
 from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick.rb:11
 from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
 from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from (irb):2

Comment: Or if possible just use your linux distribution package manager. I highly recommend it over the gem.